# Cocoa OSX custom widgets/controls

Tags: macos, cocoa, widget

I want to know how can I create custom widgets/controls in Cocoa.
Not a full tutorial, but some guidance on what to start looking into. I'm confused by custom views, Core Animation, etc. I feel lost.

I see a lot of cool looking controls, like in Reeder App, or Sparrow etc. For example:

[image: Sparrow]

The left side is a collapsable menu that includes animations etc. How can I achieve something similar? I thought of using a `WebView` + HTML + JavaScript, but that doesn't seem like a very optimized solution.

Comment: This is a very broad question -- you may want to edit it to make it more specific. Specific questions tend to work best on SO -- vague ones are likely to be closed as 'not constructive' or 'not a real question'.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Controls are views, so if custom views confuse you, you'll need to get that figured out before moving on to custom controls. Although you should really read the entire [*View Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH1-SW1), the section called [*Creating a Custom View*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html) will get you started on creating your own views. Try creating a simple view that draws a circle, for example, or the time.

When you've got views figured out, move on to custom controls. Most controls *work* about the same way. The user touches them, and the control responds by: a) tracking the user's input, b) changing its value, c) sending its action message to its target, and d) giving the user some feedback by redrawing itself. To get started, first make sure that you know how to *use* controls. Reading [*Control and Cell Programming Topics*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ControlCell/ControlCell.html) should help, and the section titled [Subclassing NSControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ControlCell/Tasks/SubclassingNSControl.html) covers (obviously) creating your own subclasses.

The example you provided is pretty clearly Apple's Mail.app. The view on the left side of the window might be an instance of [NSOutlineView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), or it might be a custom class. Either way, NSOutlineView would be a good starting point if you want to duplicate that functionality. NSOutlineView is a subclass of NSTableView, which in turn is a subclass of NSControl, which in turn is a subclass of NSView. Read [*Outline View Programming Topics*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OutlineView/OutlineView.html) for help getting started -- tables and outlines are extremely useful, but also more complicated to use than basic controls like buttons and text fields.

Comment: This a really nice send up of prerequisites that are not generally clear in cocoa. Well done

Answer (score 5):

I know it's only a part of the UI, but I've recently coded something similar to the sidebar. If you look though the source-code it may give you some help on learning how to use custom controls and cells.

You can check it out on Github:
https://github.com/iluuu1994/ITSidebar